# How the condition in "if statement" can give the section of array in which the repeated elements lie?

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

Given an array a[] of N positive integers, where elements are consecutive (sorted). Also, there is a single element which is repeating X (any variable) number of times. Now, the task is to find the element which is repeated.

```
while (start < end) 
        { 
            int mid = (start + end) / 2; 

            // if a[mid] >= mid + a[0], there is no repeating character in [start,mid]
            if (a[mid] >= mid + a[0]) 
                start = mid + 1; 

           // if a[mid] < mid + a[0], there is a repeating character in [start,mid]
            else
                end = mid; 
        }
```

Comment: This is somewhat rhetorical but what programming language is that?

Comment: @ArdentCoder Sorry sir, that was a typo. Thanks for noticing it. I have edited the code.

Comment: Advice to new contributors; there should be no typos because there should be no typing. Always _copy and paste real code_ into your question.

Comment: @matt I am using c++.

Comment: Then that should be a tag. I've added it.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I will take care from the next time.

Comment: This look like some sort of coding interview question

Comment: As it seems like you are asking how the code works here is a link to an article discussing it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-repeating-element-sorted-array-size-n/